# Функция на каждый элемент масива

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

При помощи querySelectorAll я получил массив div'ов, и теперь при нажатии на первый div нужно чтобы в консоль выводилась единица, на второй двойка и т.д. Это надо реализовать через цикл, но как я не понял. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('selector')
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // используем замыкание, иначе алерт будет выводить
    // всегда только последнее число
    elements[i].onclick = (function (index) {
         return function (e) { alert(index) }
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: только объект события прибили

Comment: @Hipster, что? Объект события будет передаваться сюда `function () { alert(index) }`, я его просто в параметрах не указал

Comment: да, верно. не очень наглядно.